# SQLite Update Not Applying Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

When I click on a ListItem, it opens up a custom dialog with 4 EditText fields.  The fields are set with current data depending on the row that is clicked. The purpose of the dialog is to allow the user to update the data (it is a financial app).  I am having trouble actually applying the update when the user clicks "submit" in the dialog.  There are no errors in the app when I run.  Here is the onclick method:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    List<Debt> values = datasource.getAllDebt();
    Debt item = values.get(position);
    final long boxId = item.getId();
    // final String BoxId = String.valueOf(boxId);
    final String BoxName = item.getName();
    final String BoxBalance = item.getBalance();
    final String BoxApr = item.getApr();
    final String BoxPayment = item.getPayment();

    // set up dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(manageDebts.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Edit Debt Details");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    // set up text
    EditText et1 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText et2 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    EditText et3 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    EditText et4 = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    et1.setText(BoxName);
    et2.setText(BoxBalance);
    et3.setText(BoxApr);
    et4.setText(BoxPayment);

    // set up button
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            datasource.updateDebt(boxId, BoxName, BoxBalance, BoxApr,
                    BoxPayment);

            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

The Update Method in my Database helper class is shown here:

```
public boolean updateDebt(long updateId, String debt_name, String debt_total, String apr, String payment) 
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, updateId);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_NAME, debt_name);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_TOTAL, debt_total);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_APR, apr);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PAYMENT, payment);
    return database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEBT, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + updateId, null) > 0;
}
```

I have verified that the COLUMN_ID and the updateId are pointing to the correct rows in the ListView and the SQL database.

Does someone see something I am not?

Comment: post your datasource.getAllDebt(); code.

Comment: I just added my entire DebtDataSource class which has most of my SQL code.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are violating a constraint with your update?  Just a guess without seeing the DB code.

EDIT

Lose the single quotes around the row id variable, that is making the DB treat it as a string, and a string compared to a number is a fail.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but I posted more DB code.  If not, what would violating a constraint do?

Comment: Cause the update to fail.  All your fields seem to be `text not null` so I's bet your trying to save a null to one of those fields ans causing the update failure.

Comment: You could try using `updateWithOnConflict` and tell it what to do when there is a constraint violation.

Comment: Using Toasts, I confirmed all the variables going into the update method are not null.

Comment: One last idea, is the row id correct?  Edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: I am passing in the correct row id (which is the long "updateId").  The whereClause is correct when I send it back using a toast.  My theory now is with the whereArgs.  And also, losing the quotes didn't change it. Though I am passing the updateId in as a "long", should it be string? Thanks again!  if your out of ideas, I understand!

Comment: It should definitely be a Long, and the updateId should **not** be in single quotes, so it should be `return database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEBT, values, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + updateId, null) > 0;

Comment: I have found something new here: if I hardcode a string (e.g. 'values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_NAME, "Random Debt");', it will update, but if I use a variable (e.g. 'values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DEBT_NAME, debtName);' it will not.  But again, using toasts, I am passing in the correct value (for example, the "debtName" variable) and it shows it is correct (I made a dummy method that simply passes the long updateId in and returns it back and it shows up on the other side as a toast - that was my method of testing).   This is quite the quandary.

Answer (score 0):

I test your code in my computer.

The update method works fine.

So I think you should post more code .

or You should check your logic.

Answer (score 0):

This will work better:

```
String whereClause = MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?";
String[] whereArgs = new String[]{ String.valueOf(updateId) };
return database.update(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_DEBT,
        values, whereClause, whereArgs) > 0;
```

The `String.valueOf()` call simply converts the ID to a String value.

Comment: thanks for the comment... does simplify the code.. but doesn't fix issue.

Comment: Where is the `database` value coming from in your `updateDebt` method? Is it a writable database? Or did you call `getReadableDatabase` instead?

Comment: I just added all of the entire class for this in the the original post.  Thanks for your help once again!

Comment: I confirmed the database is writable.  It in the last code above.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you're calling the `open()` method on your `DebtDataSource` class. Perhaps this is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a step between 2 and 3.

*Setting the variable **again**, **inside** the onClick method.*  Once the user pressed the update button, the variable had to be RE-SET to the **new** value of the EditText field.  Like this (simplified version):

```
 String name = null;
 EditText et;

 name = debt.getName();
 et.setText(name);
 onclick {
     ***name = et.getText().toString();***
     datasource.updateDebt(name);
 }
```